# “Incur companies multimillion dollar losses”

Tags: syntactic-analysis, attributive-nouns

I am struggling to formulate the following sentence

> Bad decisions lead to bad results, that would incur companies **millions dollars losses.**

What I want to say is that bad decisions will lead to multimillion losses. Does my sentence make sense? Have I used the nouns, *millions*, and *dollars* correctly?

Comment: That's an awkward phrasing of "incur" you have there. Something *incurs* costs, damages, loss(es), debts, risk(s), expenses etc.

Comment: ... but not entirely unheard of. "The fine is without prejudice to other legal liabilities that may incur companies or their leaders and without prejudice to the provisions of Article 369 of this Act ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected Sentence Structure Consideration:

> A company's bad decisions can lead to devastating results and can incur
>   losses in the millions of dollars.

**incur**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incur)

> To become liable or subject to as a result of one's actions

Comment: "A company's bad decisions" cannot be the subject of "incur losses." They can result in or lead to losses. It is the company that will incur losses as a result of its bad decisions.

Comment: [*… hospital will incur heavy losses....*](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&biw=1305&bih=660&ei=GJhUW-S4OqiL0wLdz7zgAg&q=+hospital+will+%22incur%22+heavy+losses&oq=+hospital+will+%22incur%22+heavy+losses&gs_l=psy-ab.12...10764.10764.0.12724.1.1.0.0.0.0.151.151.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.rQjUISpeYms)

Comment: Alcoa said this week it will incur as much as $14 million a month in extra expenses. A company can incur ...

Comment: Companies can incur, but decisions cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Some proposed corrections:

- Bad decisions lead to poor results, with companies incurring million dollar losses.
- Companies making bad decisions will report poor results and incur million dollar losses.
- A company's bad decisions can lead to poor results and cause it to incur million dollar losses.